What happened to the multitude Jesus raised immediately he rose from the dead?
There is a multitude of saints who came back to life minutes or hours after Jesus rose from the dead as the first born. Where did they go because I do not believe Jesus would let them die again after declaring victory over death to them when he descended to the heart of the earth.
Mathew 27:52-53

And many bodies of the saints who had fallen asleep were raised, and coming out of the tombs after his resurrection they went into the holy city and appeared to many.

Ephesians 4:7-8

But unto every one of us is given grace according to the measure of the gift of Christ. 8 Wherefore he saith, When he ascended up on high, he led captivity captive, and gave gifts unto men.

Paul is technically saying that Jesus led captivity captive or in simple terms, death became a slave of Jesus. So where did those people go because the fact that they could appear and disappear meant those were wearing heavenly bodies?
Edit:
We do not know the manner by which these saints were raised and hence we cannot know what the word appeared meant in that context but for me to appear is to suddenly manifest visibly. When scripture says an an angel appeared to Mary, what is that to you?

Which of these question types are you trying to ask here?

@curiousdannii, an overview perspective on what any Christian denomination believes happened to those souls.

Please edit the question to clearly ask that instead of sounding like you're asking for personal opinions. Though "So where did those people go because the fact that they could appear and disappear meant those were wearing heavenly bodies?" sounds like an unwarranted speculation that will make it hard for you to find an answer, as most denominations will simply say we don't know what happened to them.

It is your opinion that I do not believe Jesus would let them die again. It is also your opinion meant those were wearing heavenly bodies?. And you are choosing to link two texts together expressing an opinion that they mean the same thing. All in all, this question seems entirely based on opinion and has not accepted that some things are not revealed to us in scripture (the eventual state of those who rose immediately after Christ's resurrection) and we cannot come to sensible conclusions if we are not told.

@NigelJ, a body that appears to a mortal human being from the spirit world implies a heavenly body. They appeared to people much like Jesus appeared to the twelve. It is not an opinion as to why would God allow these souls to be held prisoner for all these years for them to go back in that state, what was the point of resurrecting them in the first place?

The 'point' was to not to draw attention to them but to draw attention to Christ's resurrection. I suggest we concentrate on that and not get distracted with the supernatural technicalities.

@NigelJ, why would Jesus declare victory over death for them and allow them to get back into this same captivity of death? A captivity that held them prisoner for thousands of years, it does not make sense at all.

They will rise again in the general resurrection. I cannot fathom why you are so concerned about this.

@NigelJ, so they are raised twice? Lazarus and the rest yeah but this was a multitude of risen saints appearing to many in Jerusalem. What about the 144000, are they the 144000 who reign with Jesus?

Now you are on to an entirely different subject . . . . . . . .

"I do not believe Jesus would let them die again" — What you believe doesn't belong in this site. ¶And does it bother you that he let Lazarus die again?

You may not realize this but you are suggesting that these folks received their resurrection bodies before Jesus did.

@MikeBorden, not me the Bible does. The most immediate verse says Jesus cried out passionately and then this resurrection happened. Not me the Bible

@NigelJ, when scripture says an angel of the Lord appeared to someone, what makes the usage of the term appear different in this context?


"the fact that they could appear and disappear meant those were wearing heavenly bodies"

That they "appeared to many" does not mean that they suddenly condensed into being (such as the way Jesus appeared within a locked room), could disappear again, and were therefore wearing heavenly bodies.  For instance, my brother in law recently flew into town, rented a car, and appeared at my doorstep.
Assuming that the verse is teaching such a thing is probably producing some confusion.  What the verse says is that they went into the holy city and appeared to many.  Literally, they exhibited themselves or were seen.  The Bible is absolutely silent about what became of them afterwards.
What we do know is that the Bible is also silent regarding the eventual disposition of others who were raised from the dead either by prophets, apostles, or Jesus Himself.  The common speculation, and it is speculation, is that these simply lived out their days and fell asleep again.

The Gospel clearly stated that they came out of the tombs and entered the city and appeared to many and not simply disappearing at will as if heavenly bodies.

@KenGraham - I think Mike Borden is quoting the unsubstantiated claim made by So Few Against So Many.

An angel of the Lord appeared to Mary, what is that to you? The same appearing done by an angel is the same done by these saints.

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/99806/what-is-the-true-meaning-of-the-word-appear-in-scripture

@Lesley. Good edit.  Much appreciated thank you.

What happened to the multitude Jesus raised immediately he rose from the dead?

And many bodies of the saints who had fallen asleep were raised, and coming out of the tombs after his resurrection they went into the holy city and appeared to many. - Matthew 27:52-53

We simply do not know as the Bible doesn't give us more details.
These events seem to foreshadow the fact of Christ’s actual Resurrection in three days.
They probably returned to their graves very shortly after this, for if they had of remained living, there would have been many legends about them.

The raising of holy people who had died points to 'the resurrection of the last days' (Isaiah 26:19; Daniel 12:2) which starts with Jesus' resurrection. It is only reported in Matthew, tied to the tearing of the temple curtain as the result of the earthquake noted in verse 51. The temple area is located on a geological fault, and the tremors from time to time cause damage to the buildings until the modern times.
Johann Bengel suggests that the "saints" or "holy people" were "those who had died either a long while before the birth of Christ, or not much after".
There is no parallel record to this event in other gospels or contemporary documents, and the account in Matthew does not have enough detail, for example, no explanation is given for the delay between the opening of the tombs on the day of Jesus' death and the appearance of raised holy people in Jerusalem after Jesus' resurrection, so the story is mainly taken for its fairly clear symbolism. The words of Matthew recalls the text of Ezekiel 37:13, "when I open your graves and bring you up out of your graves, my people", and 'the earthquake-like imagery' in Ezekiel 37:7. Nonetheless, these signs were surely known by many, that Paul could say to King Agrippa, "this thing was not done in a corner" (Acts 26:26).
Some explain the incident as referring to the grave physically opening itself up, after the gravestones broke apart from the earthquake. This was done to anticipate the resurrection of Jesus and the dead three days later. - Matthew 27:52 (Wikipedia)


As those saints came out of their tombs AFTER Christ's resurrection, how could those now-living, walking saints 'foreshadow' Christ's resurrection? I do agree with your answer except for the 'foreshadowing' sentence.

An angel of the Lord appeared to Mary, what is that to you? The same appearing done by an angel is the same done by these saints.

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/99806/what-is-the-true-meaning-of-the-word-appear-in-scripture

@Anne I believe you misread the timing of these bodies raising from the dead. The rose that the moment Christ died on the Cross and not at his Resurrection.
